# HIde keyboard navigation react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there possible way to hide keyboard Navigation from expo react-native. I am using: "react-native-keyboard-accessory". Pay attention please that on screenshot is WebView and I am calling keyboard from there.

[image]

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
            <Button onPress={checkButton} title="hee"></Button>

            <WebView
                ref={webView}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                source={{ uri: 'http://192.168.1.35:3000' }}
            />                                                                                             
        
        <KeyboardAccessoryNavigation
                doneHidden={true}
                nextHidden={true}
                previousHidden={true}                    
            />
        </View>
    </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just

```
             <KeyboardAccessoryNavigation
                        visibleOpacity={0}
                        />
```

That should do the trick!